# Is an entire function upper bounded by a polinomial a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I whant to know if the following proposition holds:

If $f$ is entire, and $p$ is a polynomial such that 
$$|f(z)| \leq |p(z)|,\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, $$ then 
there is $c \in \mathbb{C}; f(z)=cp(z)$.

If it is true, how to prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: That is true for entire functions $p$, not only for polynomials.